# Jquery Masonry is not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, safari, jquery-masonry

Hi i am using [Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) it is working on other browsers like Chrome,Firefox but it is not working in Safari Browser in 5 on windows and on Safari 8 on Mac.

The problem is that all the divs are having `top : 0px` this div  `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-item grid-item--width2" >` 
due to which all post are being are showing on top of each other here is the image link of how posts look like in safari [Image](https://i.imgsafe.org/81b3a85e0b.png)
Here is the link of the page where Masonry is not working [Masonry Gallery](http://185.14.184.118/app/inspiration-gallery)

In Masonry i am embedding facebook posts then using the Masonry container to apply Masonry styling on it.

Here is my html

```
 <div class="grid row">
  <div class="inspiration-gallery">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-item grid-item--width2" >
      <div class="inspiration-grid">
        <div class="fbpost-inspiration" id="fbpost-inspiration">
          <div class="fb-post" id="myId" data-href="post_url" data-width="200" data-height="200"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery Code to initialize Masonry

```
var $container = $('.grid');
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true
});
```

Here is my CSS

```
.grid-sizer,.grid-item { width:33.33333333%; }
```

Kindly Please help me on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using Masonry 4.Masonry 4 does not works in Safari.So i have downgraded to Masonry 3.32 Now it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [imagesloaded.js](https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) so masonry lays out the items after all the images are loaded.
 Set up your code like this:

```
var $container = $('.grid');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true
});
});
```

Safari 5 in Windows? Man, that browser version was last updated in 2012! Do more that 10 people actually use it in Windows? ;-)

Comment: actually i am not using masonry on the images i am using it on the facebook embedded posts so the imagesloaded.js is not working

Comment: Actually, you are, since the FB posts within your .grid-item all contain images or is that just an illusion? Also, you need to post the code you are using to embed the posts

Comment: the code is this   <div class="fbpost-inspiration" id="fbpost-inspiration">
          <div class="fb-post" id="myId" data-href="post_url" data-width="200" data-height="200"></div>
        </div>
   also the posts can be picture or the video of facebook

Comment: Not the html of the posts but the javascript code that is loading the posts.